# html5 - animating 2 circles like a pulse or heart beat

Tags: html, animation, geometry

I am trying to animate 2 circles like that of a beating pulse or heart beat. My idea is to draw a small circle, then a bigger one on top simulating a heart beat and then clearing it and repeating this process.

What is the best way to do this? do I really need 3 setIntervals?

draw small circle at 100ms
draw big circle at 200ms
clear rect at 300ms

If I do it this way, after a while its more of a flashing effect. If I can get one circle to do this, I want to be able to do multiple circles.

Comment: Are you using the canvas object for drawing ? or just images ?

Comment: im just using canvas and just making use of arc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in one interval.  Just have a counter and use that to figure out which circles need to be drawn.  Also, you might want to consider using settimeout and have it recursively called new settimeouts.  setinterval can get messed up depending on how long it takes to run the code in your interval.

**Edit**

Something like this..

```
var _count = 1;

function doStuff()
{ 
    switch (_count)
    {
       case 1:  drawSmallCircle(); break;
       case 2:  drawMediumCircle(); break;
       case 3:  drawLargeCircle(); break;
    }

    _count = _count == 3 ? _count = 1 : _count++;
    setTimeout(doStuff, 100);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this could work using counters. I just want to setup one first before delving into multiple. I did try the setTimeout and it doesn't work as expected like setInterval

Comment: That logic works although i've just adjusted a few things. I think that count declaration is incorrect. For case 3, to avoid the flash when you clear, just draw the small circle to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

How about you make it a bit modular..

```
var c = document.getElementById('test').getContext('2d');


function Circle(_x, _y, _r){
    var x = _x;
    var y = _y;
    var radius = _r;
    var endAngle = (Math.PI/180)*360;

    this.draw = function(canvas){
        canvas.fillStyle = "red";
        canvas.beginPath();
        canvas.arc(x,y,radius,0,endAngle ,true);
        canvas.fill();
    };

    this.delete = function(canvas){
        canvas.fillStyle = "white";
        canvas.beginPath();
        canvas.arc(x,y,radius+1,0,endAngle ,true);
        canvas.fill();
    };

    return this;
}

function Heart(_canvas, x,y,radius,increase){
    var canvas = _canvas;
    var currentState = 0;
    var states = [
        new Circle(x,y,radius),
        new Circle(x,y,radius+increase/2),
        new Circle(x,y,radius+increase)
    ];

    var that = this;


    this.beat = function(delay){
        if (delay){
            setTimeout(function(){that.beat(0);}, delay);
        }
        else{
            if (currentState == states.length){
                states[states.length-1].delete(canvas);
                that.beat(1000);
                currentState = 0;
            }
            else{
                states[currentState++].draw(canvas);
                setTimeout( function() {
                    that.beat();
                }, 150);
            }
        }
    }

    return this;
}

var heart1 = new Heart(c, 50,50,30,10);
var heart2 = new Heart(c, 130,120,40,20);
var heart3 = new Heart(c, 40,160,20,10);

heart1.beat(100);
heart2.beat(500);
heart3.beat(1300);
```

Live and beating at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/NyPZM/

Comment: :) ... well, just liked the challenge and made something.. (*programmers art of course ;)*) It is quite changeable though ..

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 1

function animate() {

switch(count)
{ 
     case 1: small(); break; 
     case 2: big(); break; 
     case 3: clear(); small(); break; 
} 

if(count == 3) 
     count = 1; 
else 
     count++;  

setTimeout(animate, 200); 

}
```